# How to fix "error C1083: Cannot open source file:" in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I was beginning to use Visual Studio 2013 to work with OpenCV.

I had completed a simple project that I need and was just doing some cleanup.
The compiler begin giving the message.

> error C1083: Cannot open source file:

What I have tried so far:

Creating a new console application in a separate file and trying to compile it, just created . -> same error.

Repairing Visual Studio using the original installation disk. -> same result on new just created project "error  c1083;

Uninstalling Visual Studio and then reinstalling it. -> same result on new just created project "error c1083"

Things I have noticed. My compiler is not creating a .pch file or at least I cannot find it. I have precompiled headers enabled. /Yc for stdafx.cpp and /Yu. for other files if I have any.

If I use a previously created project that was working the IDE will run it, but if I change anything in the source file I get the same error.

I have tried placing projects in very short paths and in the normal location for the compiler.

Solution explorer sees and will open the source file.

I am beginning to think something is corrupted in my operating system. (Windows 7).
I have been thinking I might format the disk and reinstall Windows, but thought I might ask for suggestions on this problem first.

"
What do you mean by 'doing some cleanup'? It is quite unlikely that your OS is corrupted. There is probably something wrong with your project properties, but I couldn't tell you what without better information"

This was just a simple project to place cross hairs on the input from a USB microscope which was spindle mounted on a CNC milling machine for centering purposes. I was just changing the on screen position and size of the cross hairs. Then when I recompiled the problem started. I thought it might be a corrupted file because of the fact that it persisted after uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio. The fact that a freshly generated project would not compile made me suspicious.

"
Looks like something in your Project/Properties is not right. It is looking for the files in the wrong directory"

You are probably correct, but I am a novice and have spent many hours trying to find what it may be any suggestions for what settings to change would be greatly appreciated.

"
Do your TMP and TEMP environment variables point to directories that (1) exist (2) you have write permission to and (3) have free space? "

Yes sir The environment variables are set and the directory has read write permission. There is > 1T of free disk space.

"
Also try (with VS closed) deleting the registry keys HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 and 12.0_Config and the directory %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0, then open VS and try again with a fresh project. This will cause VS to regenerate all caches and "transient" information (it will also reset all your settings, so beware)."

Sir: I deleted the keys and the directory you recommended, generated a fresh project and tried to compile it. The compiler generated the same error.  I genuinely appreciate the suggestion.

"VS only allows closed source development"

Pointed, consider the source of VS.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doing some cleanup'? It is quite unlikely that your OS is corrupted. There is probably something wrong with your project properties, but I couldn't tell you what without better information.

Comment: Looks like something in your Project/Properties is not right. It is looking for the files in the wrong directory.

Comment: Do your `TMP` and `TEMP` environment variables point to directories that (1) exist (2) you have write permission to and (3) have free space?

Comment: Also try (with VS closed) deleting the registry keys `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0` and `12.0_Config` and the directory `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`, then open VS and try again with a fresh project. This will cause VS to regenerate all caches and "transient" information (it will also reset all your settings, so beware).

Comment: VS only allows closed source development